# IdentityServer4 with multiple instances

Tags: docker, identityserver4

I have two docker containers with the same image of our OAuth Server with IdentityServer4 managed with Docker Swarm (I don't take care of this).

The problem is that the token sometimes is valid and sometimes not when it's valid (401 Unauthorized).

We tried leaving only one instance running and the problem was solved, but we need two.

How can I configure multiple instances of the server?

Notes:

- We are using the `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()`. I don't know if it will affect or not.
- It's a test environment with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Comment: is your token jwt, not reference? otherwise you need to share your persisted grant store. you need to share the store anyway when using refresh tokens. if you use any caches (for instance in custom user store implementation, it's also better to share, using redis or so)

Comment: It's a JWT self contained token.

Comment: Then you have to distinguish what exact step of validation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the tempkey.rsa file was different in both instances of the IdentityServer.

I had to configure the file with the build action to "copy always" to be included in the built project and therefore in the docker image.

I know that in production it should not be used in this way, but it was an urgent need for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many instances of the Identity Server 4 web app as you want as long as they:

- Share the signing credentials (if you are using `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` that should be fine)
- Issue tokens using the same issuer uri (you can to `{baseUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration` page to check if the issuer uri on your two instances of identity server 4 is the same)

Nothing else should really matter as far as your token validation is concerned. Generally the token validation involves downloading the discovery document info describing the authority provider and the public keys to verify the signature of the tokens against the respected issuer.

Comment: Please explain how to Issue tokens using the same issuer uri. Webapi will connect to it to check.