# Multiple instances of IdentityServer4 with signing credentials from AzureKeyvault

Tags: identityserver4, azure-keyvault

My identityserver4 is deployed into AKS with replicas to 1. But when I set the replica count to more than 1, I started seeing problems.

Sometimes authentication validation works sometimes it doesn't. As per the documentation from IdentityServer4 portal, if we use more than one instance of the identityserver is running then we have to make sure that the same signing credentials should be used across all the instances. I have used Azure keyvault Keys to for signing credentials following this [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Outsourcing-IdentityServer4-Token-Signing-to-Azure-Key-Vault).
But I'm still facing the problem. I have also made sure that the discovery url is same even when there are multiple instances runnings as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55749666/924991). Please advise.

sample Startup code for fetching the Keys from Azure keyVault -

```
var keyClient = new KeyClient(
        new Uri(""), // e.g. https://scottbrady91-test.vault.azure.net/
        new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId: "",
            clientId: "",
            clientSecret: ""));

    Response<KeyVaultKey> response = keyClient.GetKey(""); // e.g. IdentityServerSigningKeyEcc

    AsymmetricSecurityKey key;
    string algorithm;

    if (response.Value.KeyType == KeyType.Ec)
    {
        ECDsa ecDsa = response.Value.Key.ToECDsa();
        key = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecDsa) {KeyId = response.Value.Properties.Version};
        
        // parse from curve
        if (response.Value.Key.CurveName == KeyCurveName.P256) algorithm = "ES256";
        else if (response.Value.Key.CurveName == KeyCurveName.P384) algorithm = "ES384";
        else if (response.Value.Key.CurveName == KeyCurveName.P521) algorithm = "ES521";
        else  throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    else if (response.Value.KeyType == KeyType.Rsa)
    {
        RSA rsa = response.Value.Key.ToRSA();
        key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa) {KeyId = response.Value.Properties.Version};

        // you define
        algorithm = "PS256";
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
    
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
        .AddSigningCredential(key, algorithm);
```

Comment: What does your init code look like that sets up the signing keys?

Comment: I have updated my question with sample startup code for fetching the keys from keyvault

Comment: That looks fine, I suspect the issue is the one Tore refers to in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that might give you issues is the [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it is in charge of protection the session cookies involved. If you want the session cookies to be valid across the instances, then they need to share the same encryption keys (key ring).

See [Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

I also did blog about this here:
[Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)

Comment: This was going to be my next question. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm not using Aspnet core cookie based websites for logging in. I have react app and using jwt token based authentication. So do I still need take care of Data Protection API?

Comment: I still think you need to configure it because IdentityServer also sets its own session Cookie when you do login.

Comment: Unless my understanding is wrong, jwt based auth doesnt depend on the cookie based. I checked the github repo as well - check this https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3843#issuecomment-555901267

Comment: Not for the tokens them self, but cookies are indirectly involved. In ASP.NET Core the tokens and identity is by default stored in a cookie. The received ID-token is converted into a IClaimsPrincipal user and it is stored in a cookie by default. IdentityServer also sets its own "session" cookie when you authenticate.

Comment: I have setup the Dataprotection with persist to storage account and use the key from Keyvault. However, I still face the same error when replica count is 2 
- fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenRequestValidator[0]
      Invalid authorization code...

Comment: When you get invalid authorization code, I suspect that the client instance that handles the initial authentication request is not the same instance that handles the last step in the authentication process. It should be the same instance through the entire authentication/login cycle.

Comment: Isnt that the problem we were trying to solve by making sure that the Signing keys are same, dataprotectionapi to be same across multiple instances? With multiple instances running how can I get the same instance to go through entire auth/login cycle?

Comment: for example the client sets the PKCE value in the client and the exact same client must also be the that handles the final step of the authentication flow. This all happens before the Data Protection API is involved. DP is only involved when a succesfully authenticated user is converted into a cookie. The client also sets the state parameter, that must be the same through the entire auth cycle.

Comment: I'm using a React client using oidc. It redirects to the Identityserver login page. Here users enters the credentials and clicks login. After user has been validated. It redirects to the react app with the access token. React client then uses this access token and POST /connect/token. Here it fails as token validation fails if the request goes to the other instance. So yes the same client is making all the calls.

Comment: Are you using the access token or access code to access POST /connect/token?

Comment: I'm using access code. I have finally managed to fix this by setting up OperationalStore DB. That did the trick.